# Check if Magento is running in production mode

Tags: magento2, custom, magento2.3.4, production-mode

I am creating a custom store implementation and I need to check if the store is in production mode or not via code. 
What is the fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: you want to without code right ???

Comment: @Jinesh now i've the office server down, i will implement your solution in the 
afternoon.

Comment: @mohit-patel there is some alternative to get it?

Comment: so my question is have you want production mode using command line or programatically?

Comment: php bin/magento deploy:mode:show you tried this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @return \Magento\Framework\App\State */
$state = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
/** @var bool $isDeveloperMode */
$isDeveloperMode = \Magento\Framework\App\State::MODE_DEVELOPER === $state->getMode();
```

You can get using magento coding standard

```
protected $_appState;

public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState )
{
    $this->_appState = $appState;
}

public function doSomething() {
    switch ( $this->_appState->getMode() ) {
        case \Magento\Framework\App\State::MODE_DEFAULT:
            // Action for default mode
            break;
        case \Magento\Framework\App\State::MODE_PRODUCTION:
            // Action for production mode
            break;
        case \Magento\Framework\App\State::MODE_DEVELOPER:
            // Action for developer mode
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Run below command in command line.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```